# Controller return values but not show in JqGrid in ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid, controller return list of values but values are not showing on jqgrid. Rows created button groupid, and name not shown. I also use break point controller return datatable correctly but not show on jqgrid.
I also attach the screenshort you can see the actual result.

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult mfollowsummary(int id)
{
    using (objSqlCon = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Group_Id,Group_Name from Groups where Comp_Id=" + 1 + "", objSqlCon);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
               
        objSqlCon.Open();
        sd.Fill(dt);
        objSqlCon.Close();
        string JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
        var people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Groups>>(JSONString);

        return Json(people);
    }
}
```

**Screenshort**
[Return Result of function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rfFI.jpg)

**Jqgrid Link**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.5/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.5/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var $grid = $("#jqGrid");

        $grid.jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("mfollowsummary")',
            datatype: 'json',
            postData: {
            },
            jsonReader: { id: 'Group_Id' },
            colModel: [
                { name: 'GroupId', width: 20, hidden: false, editable: true, editable: "disabled" },
                { name: 'GroupName', width: 200, frozen: true, editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'] } },

            ],
            loadonce: true,
            navOptions: {
                reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true }
            },
            formEditing: {

                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterEdit: true,
                savekey: [true, 13],
                reloadGridOptions: {

                    fromServer: true
                }
            },
            forceClientSorting: true,
            viewrecords: true,

            autowidth: true,
            shrinkToFit:true,
            height: 350,
            rowNum: 100,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30, 50, 100, 500],
            pager: "#jqGridPager",
         
            rownumbers: true,
            sortname: 'Group_Name',
            sortorder: 'Group_Name',
     

            loadComplete: function () {
                //$("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", "#f0f8ff");

            },
        });


        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("setFrozenColumns");
    });


</script>
```

**Result Screenshot**
[Return Function Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu2B4.jpg)

**HTML**

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
       <table id="jqGrid" class="table"></table>
 </div>
 <div id="jqGridPager"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only set coorect the id, but not the names. Your colModel names does not respect the data returned. Try with the following colModel.

```
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Group_Id', width: 20, hidden: false, editable: true, editable: "disabled" },
            { name: 'Group_Name', width: 200, frozen: true, editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'] } },

        ],
```

Note names **Group_Id**, **Group_Name**, which corresponds to waht you return from the server.

**JSON Response**
[JSON Response screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhITe.jpg)

Comment: I use this line of code but problem is still same.

Comment: Can you please publish your response from the server? Use debug console for this purpose.

Comment: This is the result when i debug 
i also post the image of result below the controller section

001 MEMBERS ACCOUNT
002 VENDORS
003 CORPORATE SOCIAL RESPONSIBILITY
004 EMPLOYEES
005 AGENTS

Comment: I mean the resul seen in browser console. Where the grid is pres Ctrl+Shit + J and see the JSON response from the server. That is the part that is important. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)

Comment: Hello @TonyTomov i have attach the screenshot of json response in browser console.

Comment: You use the unsupported  free-jqGrid. With Guriddo jqGrid (commercial) you setup with this data works perfectly. Demo [here](http://guriddo.net/demo/demos/jqgrid/support/zeeshan/)

Comment: @ZEESHAN it is a good practice to explain where the problem was and how you solve it. This will help othrer people having similar problem.